# CodeIgniter - accessing $config variable in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Pretty often I need to access `$config` variables in views.
I know I can pass them from controller to `load->view()`.
But it seems excessive to do it explicitly.

Is there some way or trick to access `$config` variable from CI views without
disturbing controllers with spare code?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

`$this->config->item()` works fine.

For example, if the config file contains `$config['foo'] = 'bar';` then `$this->config->item('foo') == 'bar'`

Comment: nice helpful answer

Comment: In CodeIgniter 4 what is the alternative?

Answer (score 30):

Also, the Common function `config_item()` works pretty much everywhere throughout the CodeIgniter instance. Controllers, models, views, libraries, helpers, hooks, whatever.

Comment: Thanks for this -- I was having trouble accessing a config value from a hook. For anyone else, this works great.

Comment: But, `config_item()` doesn't have the collision protection which is available in `$this->config->item()`

Answer (score 16):

You can do something like that:

```
$ci = get_instance(); // CI_Loader instance
$ci->load->config('email');
echo $ci->config->item('name');
```

Comment: Actualy within a view $this refers to CI_Loader and get_instance() refers to the CI_Base() as always.

Answer (score 8):

`$this->config->item('config_var')` did not work for my case.

I could only use the `config_item('config_var');` to echo variables in the view

Answer (score 4):

Your controller should collect all the information from databases, configs, etc. There are many good reasons to stick to this. One good reason is that this will allow you to change the source of that information quite easily and not have to make any changes to your views.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it. In config.php

```
$config['HTML_TITLE'] = "SO TITLE test";
```

In applications/view/header.php (assuming html code)

```
<title><?=$this->config->item("HTML_TITLE");?> </title>
```

[image: Example of Title]

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I need to access config variables I tend to use: $this->config->config['variable_name'];

Comment: I don't know why but since today $this->config->item('var_name'); didn't work anymore for me.. thanks for the alternative way. just wondering.. is this method legal?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $this->config->config['ur config file']
```

If your config file also come to picture you have to access like this for example I include an app.php in config folder I have a variable

```
$config['50001'] = "your  message"
```

Now I want access in my controller or model .

Try following two  cases one should work

**case1:**

```
$msg = $this->config->item('ur config file');

echo $msg['50001'];    //out put:  "your message";
```

**case2:**

```
 $msg = $this->config->item('50001');

 echo $msg;    //out put:  "your message"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$config['cricket'] = 'bat';`  in config.php file

`$this->config->item('cricket')`  use this in view

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to accessing config variable into controller than use

```
$this->config->item('{variable name which you define into config}');
```

If you are trying to accessing the config variable into outside the controller(helper/hooks) then use

```
$mms = get_instance();  
$mms->config->item('{variable which you define into config}');
```

Answer (score -1):

Example, if you have:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.example.com'
```

set in your **config.php** then

```
echo base_url();
```

This works very well almost at every place.

/* Edit */

This might work for the latest versions of codeigniter (4 and above).